# Node-Gyp to build Socket.io not working can't open winsock2.h (Windows 10 64x)

Tags: node.js, sockets, msbuild, windows-10, node-gyp

Questions like this appear to be rampant, but none of the ones I've found solve my issues regarding not being able to compile when running `npm install --save socket.io`.  The current error (aka. error #4) below is preventing a build of socket.io.  First I found this [solutions](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp), followed by this [solution](http://www.serverpals.com/blog/building-using-node-gyp-with-visual-studio-express-2015-on-windows-10-pro-x64).  Finally, found this post on [GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629) where I've installed [Visual C++ build tools](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-153196245) suggested a couple days ago, which still can't get a build to complete successfully.  Any other suggestions?

**Current Error**

```
$ npm install --save socket.io
npm WARN package.json @ No repository field.
npm WARN package.json @ No license field.

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install D:\projects\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\projects\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "D:\installs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version  number. [D:\projects\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
  validation.cc
c:\users\mtpultz\.node-gyp\4.2.2\include\node\uv-win.h(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock2.h': No such file or directory [D:\projects\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules \utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\installs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "D:\\installs\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\installs\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\projects\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install D:\projects\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild
```

This seems waaay to complicated just so socket.io can be required in this nodejs application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this works if you check both [SDK 8 and 10](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-156889130) when installing [VS C++ Build Tools](https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/4/C/E4C8C3B5-7B82-4069-AD59-3A7FF8F87C74/VisualCppBuildTools_Full.exe).

Alternatively you can also pull it into a VM like Homestead and run `npm install --save socket.io`, but the above solution definitely worked on Windows 10.